# What game are António, Carlos and Jobim playing?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

In Cowboy Bebop, there are three men that are seen recurrently: António, Carlos and Jobim.
They are most often found playing cards.

[image: António, Carlos and Jobim]

What game are they playing? I don't remember it ever being stated in the anime. Was it ever stated elsewhere?

Comment: @luserdroog they are named after Brazilian songwriter and musician, Antonio Carlos Jobim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was never revealed in the anime and it isn't said on the [wiki](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Three_Old_Men) or anywhere [else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Cowboy_Bebop_characters#Antonio.2C_Carlos.2C_and_Jobim) of [relevance](http://pierceshane.awardspace.biz/threeoldmen.html).

> They seem on speaking terms with many supporting characters, and
>   though they run into the main characters often there is not much
>   attention paid to them (or even mention that the main characters have
>   seen them before).

This is the closest I have ever seen their [mention to a card game](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/CowboyBebopSession3HonkyTonkWoman).

> ... Spike
>   and Jet have arrived and ready to hit the tables, with Jet having a
>   good feeling after having a dream involving Charlie Parker. The two
>   split off with Jet playing the slots while Spike mills around the
>   tables, gaining some chips after helping three old men win a card
>   game. Eventually he settles on a Blackjack table where Alice is
>   dealing ...

Here are all the [episodes](http://www.rfblues.net/Omake/Notice/#acj) they have been featured in and it isn't said or shown in any. So it was never stated and in general they mainly acted as comic relief.